# React Native Expo | Should wipe data every time when npx expo run:android or will get error

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-emulator

If I didn't wipe data when I restart the React native expo by `npx expo run:android`, will get the error

`Error: It took too long to start the Android emulator:...`

then

`This computer is not authorized for developing on ...`

Even when I follow this solution

https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/authorize-android-device.md

still can't run until i wipe emulator data.

I think it about authorized device with computer, But everytime the agree popup show,
it very fast to disapper that I can't click.

I don't konw how to deal with this problem.

[image]